# Java - Decimal color to RGB color

Tags: java, colors, decimal, rgb

I have a decimal (not hexadecimal) color code and, using Java, I need to convert it to the three RGB colors.

So for example, 16777215 (pure white) needs to get converted to Red: 255 Green: 255 Blue: 255. 
65280 (pure green) needs to get converted to Red: 0 Green 255: Blue: 0 
[Here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/hexadecimal-decimal-colors.html) is a converter for more examples.

---

Just doing some small calculations and playing with the calculator on the page linked above, I have determined:

- Red equals 65536 (256^2)

  - (255x65536 = 16711680, aka pure red)
- Green equals 256 (256^1)

  - (255x256 = 65280, aka pure green)
- Blue equals 1 (256^0)

  - (255x1 = 255, aka pure blue)

I can tell it obviously has something to do with bytes, but I am missing that last little bit. I am not the best with the whole concept of bits/bytes/etc and how it interacts with Java, so it is likely fairly simple.

So, anyone know the best way of going about this? What would be the best way to convert a single numerical decimal color into the three separate RGB values using java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do

```
Color color = new Color(16777215);
int red = color.getRed();
int green = color.getGreen();
int blue = color.getBlue();
```

Comment: Java has a straight-forward Color constructor taking the single int that works too.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Did not know the whole Color thing existed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 16):

You where telling right: RGB values are encoded as bytes in a `int`. R is byte 2, G is byte 1 and B is byte 0, summing up to a 24bit color depth. Depending on the endianess, this could be a possible representation.

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  <-- 32bit int
         ^             ^      ^
         |             |      |
         +--red here   |      +--green here
              8bit     |            8bit
                       |
                       +--blue here
                             8bit
```

You can extract RGB values with some bit shift and masking:

```
int red = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
int green = (color >> 8) & 0xff;
int blue = color & 0xff;
```

Comment: This seems like it would work for what I needed, and much better information, but the Color thing Reimeus posted does exactly what I need and looks much more simple. Thanks very much, wish I could select both as best answer

Comment: Yeah I agree. I did not delete this because the ASCII art might help you understand how RGB values have been packed in the number you have. You should definitely go @Reimeus way.

Comment: Great answer! It can be used in multiple programming languages with the same solution. Even when there is no Color object available to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the channels out by simple bitwise operations.

```
int r = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
int g = (color >> 8)  & 0xff;
int b = color & 0xff;
```

From there, it should be easy to do whatever you want with the color information.

Answer (score 1):

Decimal, hexadecimal: **does not matter**. Your computer uses binary representations internally.

You may have noticed that `0xFF00 == 65280`.

Decimal and Hexadecimal are *user* representations.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a bit late, but...

```
int r = color / 65536;
int g = (color - r * 65536) / 256;
int b = color - r * 65536 - g * 256;
```

This is really doing the exact same thing as the binary shifts even though it doesn't use bitwise operators. This also only works when using valid RGB values (meaning each value is an integer between 0 and 255). For efficiency, however, I would use the binary shifts from the above answers.